# Where was command executed

Tags: command-history

The `history` list the commands executed, is there anyway to know where the command was executed, i mean in which directory ?

Comment: There is no easy way no. If you know the time it was executed, you can try to maybe match execution time to file modification times across the file system

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know unless you did some previous settings to the history saving. Like those [Link](http://www.compbiome.com/2010/07/bash-per-directory-bash-history.html)

Comment: @StephenKitt i edited my comment with a link of settings im referring to!